# Unable to red .mat file with JMatI/O library in Java project

Tags: java, matlab

I am trying to read a .mat file using JMatI/O library in a Java project but when I create the instance of MatFileReader it throws an exception and I don´t know what could be the problem. Here is the code:

```
public class signalSource {

    public static String filePath = "aaaaaaa.mat";

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        MatFileReader mfr = null;

        try {
            mfr = new MatFileReader(filePath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading .mat file");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println(mfr.getContent());
    }
}
```

And this is the error:

```
com.jmatio.io.MatlabIOException: Incorrect matlab array class: single
    at com.jmatio.io.MatFileReader.readMatrix(Unknown Source)
    at com.jmatio.io.MatFileReader.readMatrix(Unknown Source)
    at com.jmatio.io.MatFileReader.readData(Unknown Source)
    at com.jmatio.io.MatFileReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.jmatio.io.MatFileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.jmatio.io.MatFileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I want to see the content of the file, that is a group of structures that contain five variables each.

Comment: Judging by the [documentation of JMatIO](https://github.com/diffplug/JMatIO), you should likely switch to [MFL](https://github.com/HebiRobotics/MFL). It might be that the code is too old and can't handle some of the newer .mat files. If you _have to use this library_, I would try to [debug](https://github.com/diffplug/JMatIO/blob/master/src/main/java/ca/mjdsystems/jmatio/io/MatFileReader.java#L1287) the library itself and see what causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

The original version of JMatIO didn't support single precision matrices. You'd need to use a newer fork like [MatFileRW](https://github.com/diffplug/matfilerw), or switch to the more recent [MFL](https://github.com/HebiRobotics/MFL) library.